# include external website inside div in jsp

Tags: jsp

I would like to include an external website (e.g. www.example.com) in a div in my jsp page. I don’t want to use frames since it’s not advisable.

I tried searching online for a solution, but all what I found was including an internal webpage (e.g. webpage.jsp)…

I’ll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, using frames is indeed not advisable if it concerns dividing/including **local** content (which is/was the most common abuse of frames). But it is definitely advisable if it concerns **external** content. For local content you should rather be using server-side includes such as `<jsp:include>`.

As to the concrete question, if the HTML response of the external website does not collide with the HTML response of your own JSP page (i.e. it does not return a complete `<html>` document which would make your final HTML response completely [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/) because of duplicate/nested `<html>` elements, but it returns some context-independent HTML fragment, e.g. `<span>blah</span>`), then you can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:import>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) for this.

```
<c:import url="http://external.com/some/fragment.html" />
```

But if it returns a complete `<html>` document and/or is context-dependent, then you really have to use `<iframe>` or to bring a proxy servlet in between. For a concrete kickoff example of such a servlet, check this answer: [Make HttpURLConnection load web pages with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280655/make-httpurlconnection-load-web-pages-with-images/6283394#6283394).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to face several issues if you want to include an external page in a `div` tag only, to name a few:

1. handling links inside the external website
2. cookie management
3. resource management (images, css, javascript)

There are different options to handle requirements like this:

1. iFrame; it's not nice but why isn't it advisable?
2. server-side reverse proxy; may become complex as you have to filter external links (see #3)
3. simple frame (somehow outdated)
4. well-defined interface provided by the external system (e.g. some RESTful stuff)

To conclude: there is no easy way of providing an external page in a `div` only.